# Lwuit non static dialog having issue?

Tags: java, java-me, dialog, lwuit

When I use

```
Dialog form = new Dialog("Login");
Label userL = new Label("Username");
Label passL = new Label("Password");
TextField user = new TextField();
TextField pass  = new TextField();
 Container c = new Container();
c.addComponent (userL);
c.addComponent (user);
c.addComponent (passL);
c.addComponent (pass);

form.addComponent (c);

form.showDialog();
```

The container is coming in dialog but not inside dialog body....

Can anyone help me????

Comment: Why are you creating an intermediate container? You should add your components directly to the Dialog.

Comment: Even if I do that, the result is the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear do you mean the `DialogBody` style doesn't apply?

The DialogBody style is only applied manually in the static dialog methods. You should use `c.setUIID("DialogBody");`

Alternatively you might be referring to a change that was done in the current SVN to the way dialogs behave which changed the way dialog styles act. You can learn more about that change in this post: http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/10/tips-about-compatibility-issues-with-my.html